# Getting access to users mic via chrome background extention or background app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to have my app pick up the key words "Okay Chrome" It's not picking up any sort of audio. I'm not new to javascript, but I am new to making chrome apps/extensions. Is there some sort of way, that I might have missed, that allows developers to get mic input from an unpackaged app/extent ion, if so, how?

Presently, I have the Annyang library running as a background script and as another background scripts I have the following

```
function openBrowser(){
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.extension.getURL('main.html'), 
    type: 'panel'
  });
};
if (annyang) {
  var commands = {
     'Ok Chrome': openBrowser
  };
 annyang.addCommands(commands);
 annyang.start();
 annyang.debug();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hasn't been fully implemented yet (at least in normal chrome), but its supposed to work with `chrome.audio` api.

You'd obviously declare it with the following permissions:

```
"permissions": [
  "audio",
  ...
],
```

And you'd get access to methods outlined here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/audio

As of now it only works one the dev channel chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is at this time, besides the coming-soon method mentioned by @turnt.

My solution to this would be to present a window, etc., when your extension is first installed. This is the window that would request access to the user's microphone (allowing them to grant permission - which I believe is what you *don't* have now.)